# How to make some text of Text widget unerasable in tkinter text widget?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to make a terminal with text widget in tkinter.I want that current path is written in
Text widget and anyone cant erase it and on the other hand thay can write their command.

Answer (score 0):

Set the state first to `Normal` and then change the state to `Disabled` following a `text.insert` for a text *widget*.

```
text.configure(state='Normal')
text.insert('TEXT')
text.configure(state='Disabled')
```